# Problem of linear Algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

F is a 2 * 2 matrix that defines a transformation that reflects across three different lines in R2 and then rotates by an angle of 90 degree clockwise. Is F invertible?

Comment: **Hint :** A compose of invertible transformations is invertible.

Comment: If you keep asking questions like this, you will not be able to ask any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: the inverse is the matrix representing the transformation which rotates $90^\circ$ counterclockwise, then reflects across the third line (which is the inverse of reflecting across said line), then across the second (same as before), then across the first (idem).

Comment: You should precise that all the involved transformations are their own inverse, otherwise the OP can think that the inverse of a composition is just the composition of the transformations in the other order... :)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Just the last three, but I get your point. Personally I think it will go over his head anyways.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my brain read $180^°$ for some reason... :)